# How to print content of textbox in IE9 in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have  to print a text box with its value using JavaScript when user enter the value at run time but the below code is not compatible with IE9+ textbox is within div tag

```
Print:function()
{
     var divtoprint = document.getElementById('div1');

     var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
     popupWin.document.open();
     popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divtoprint.innerHTML + '</html>');
     popupWin.document.close();
 }
```

Please can you help?

Comment: What's with the `Print:` part of your code?  Is this part of an object literal?

Comment: no textbox is within the div tag it onnly printing it in IE9+ for lower version it is orking

Answer (score 1):

I have changed :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function print(){
     var divtoprint = document.getElementById('main-div').innerHTML;
     alert(divtoprint);
     var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=500,height=400');
     popupWin.document.open();
     popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divtoprint + '</html>');
     popupWin.document.close();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
 <div id="main-div">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
    </div>
    <input type="button" value=" Print Terms " onClick="print()">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and it works f9 in ie9,ie10.

here is the screen shot in my ie 10:

[image]

and this: [image]

Comment: the code which I posted is working fine  with lower version of IE9+ but not with it I simply want to aslo print content of texbox within the textbox only as it is but the code which I posted is not compatible with IE9+ but our Requriment is It should be compatible with IE9+ can you plz give any suggestion on it

Comment: pls see the edited answer and tell me is it ok or u need something else.

Comment: the only value is printed but I want the textbox should  appears with  its value in it this is my concern i thnik I miss to to tell you this thing can you plz try it

Comment: you give static value to the textbox so its working but when user enter the value to it then it is not working can you plz check this when a  user enter the value to textbox at run time  in IE9 specially

Answer (score 0):

IE has some strict validation of html.
Chrome, firefox and the other browsers are not so strict.

In your code you are missing the closing body tag.
You will need to this tag and i sure your code will work in IE.

Replace:

```
popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divtoprint.innerHTML + '</html>');
```

By:

```
popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divtoprint.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
```

At the end of the line I added the closing tag.

Comment: Can you debug and see if your call gets even triggered?
In IE9 press F12 and go to the "Script" tab.
Put a breakpoint inside the Print function. You can add breakpoints by clicking in the left side gray margin. after you done this press the play button to start debugging. And then test your page.

Comment: it doesn't show any error it simply print the page without the enter value of textbox in IE9. and the same code is working fine with lower version of IE

Comment: If you debug what is the value of "divtoprint.innerHTML".
You can see this by adding it to the watch or hovering over the line in the code while debugging.

Comment: the only value is printed but I want the textbox should appears with its value in it this is my concern i thnik I miss to to tell you this thing can you plz try it

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt this can be done to be honest. Besides, a common practice for printing webpages is attaching a stylesheet for printing, in which you are hiding all elements but the ones you want to print.
Here is a nice blog article about that:
[print stylesheets](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml)

Here is a quick example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style media="print">
        .noprint { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body">
    <div>
        <div id="main-div">
            <input type="text" id="mytextbox" name="FirstName" value="Mickey"/>
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="noprint" value=" Print Terms " onClick="window.print()">
    </div>
</body>
```

Now if your user goes to "print preview" in their browser, they won't see the "print" button (and the same way the page will be printed when they click "print" button on the page)

I hope that will help you.